# kernel 6.5.0.14 errors on Marvell 88SE9230

Tags: kernel, kubuntu

I am running Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS and upgraded today to the latest kernel, `6.5.0-14`.  Previous kernel was `6.2.0-39`.
After the upgrade and reboot, all the drives came up, and no errors or issues accessing the drives.

However, syslog showed these two messages repeating every second:

```
ata8: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 300)  
ata8.00: configured for UDMA/66
```

ata8 is the Marvell controller itself:

```
10:43:51 root@linux2:/var/log > lsscsi  
[0:0:0:0]    disk    ATA      ST16000NM001G-2K SN02  /dev/sda  
[1:0:0:0]    disk    ATA      ST16000NM001G-2K SN02  /dev/sdb  
[2:0:0:0]    disk    ATA      WDC  WUH721816AL W232  /dev/sdc  
[3:0:0:0]    disk    ATA      WDC  WUH721816AL W232  /dev/sdd  
[7:0:0:0]    process Marvell  Console          1.01  -        
[8:0:0:0]    disk    ATA      SanDisk SDSSDH3  20RL  /dev/sde  
[9:0:0:0]    disk    ATA      SanDisk SDSSDH3  40RL  /dev/sdf  
[10:0:0:0]   disk    ATA      ST16000NM000J-2T SN02  /dev/sdg  
[11:0:0:0]   disk    ATA      ST16000NM000J-2T SN02  /dev/sdh  
[12:0:0:0]   disk    ATA      Samsung SSD 860  1B6Q  /dev/sdi  
[13:0:0:0]   disk    ATA      Samsung SSD 870  2B6Q  /dev/sdj  
[16:0:0:0]   disk    ATA      Samsung SSD 870  2B6Q  /dev/sdk  
[17:0:0:0]   disk    ATA      Samsung SSD 860  3B6Q  /dev/sdl  
[N:0:1:1]    disk    CT500P2SSD8__1                             /dev/nvme0n1  
[N:1:5:1]    disk    Samsung SSD 980 500GB__1                   /dev/nvme1n1

grep ata8 /var/log/messages | less

2024-01-11T07:49:05.430308-05:00 linux2 kernel: [    1.551856] ata8: SATA max UDMA/133 abar m2048@0xfc940000 port 0xfc940480 irq 43  
2024-01-11T07:49:05.430510-05:00 linux2 kernel: [    1.871920] ata8: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 300)  
2024-01-11T07:49:05.430517-05:00 linux2 kernel: [    1.993399] ata8.00: ATAPI: MARVELL VIRTUAL, 1.09, max UDMA/66
2024-01-11T07:49:05.430524-05:00 linux2 kernel: [    1.997151] ata8.00: configured for UDMA/66  
2024-01-11T07:49:05.430788-05:00 linux2 kernel: [    2.487046] ata8: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 300)  
2024-01-11T07:49:05.430792-05:00 linux2 kernel: [    2.488106] ata8.00: configured for UDMA/66  
2024-01-11T07:49:05.430804-05:00 linux2 kernel: [    2.835265] ata8: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 300)  
2024-01-11T07:49:05.430808-05:00 linux2 kernel: [    2.836435] ata8.00: configured for UDMA/66
```

Thousands of the SATA link up and configured for UDMA/66 messages follow.

I rebooted to the previous kernel version, 6.2.0-39.
syslog messages for ata8:

```
2024-01-11T09:56:52.420037-05:00 linux2 kernel: [    1.539898] ata8: SATA max UDMA/133 abar m2048@0xfc940000 port 0xfc940480 irq 45  
2024-01-11T09:56:52.420274-05:00 linux2 kernel: [    2.201680] ata8.00: ATAPI: MARVELL VIRTUAL, 1.09, max UDMA/66
```

from lshw:

```
*-pci:1  
description: PCI bridge  
product: Matisse PCIe GPP Bridge  
vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]  
physical id: 2  
bus info: pci@0000:03:02.0  
version: 00  
width: 32 bits  
clock: 33MHz  
capabilities: pci pm pciexpress msi ht normal_decode bus_master cap_list  
configuration: driver=pcieport  
resources: irq:34 ioport:e000(size=4096) memory:fc900000-fc9fffff  
*-sata  
description: SATA controller  
product: 88SE9230 PCIe 2.0 x2 4-port SATA 6 Gb/s RAID Controller  
vendor: Marvell Technology Group Ltd.  
physical id: 0  
bus info: pci@0000:05:00.0  
logical name: scsi0  
logical name: scsi1  
logical name: scsi2  
logical name: scsi3  
logical name: scsi7  
version: 11  
width: 32 bits  
clock: 33MHz  
capabilities: sata pm msi pciexpress ahci_1.0 bus_master cap_list rom emulated  
configuration: driver=ahci latency=0  
resources: irq:43 ioport:e050(size=8) ioport:e040(size=4) ioport:e030(size=8) ioport:e020(size=4) ioport:e000(size=32) memory:fc940000-fc9407ff memory:fc900000-fc93ffff
```

Motherboard: ASUS ROG Crosshair VIII Dark Hero
CPU: AMD Ryzen 9 5950X

For now, I'm just sticking with `6.2.0-39` but will eventually need to upgrade to a more current version of the kernel.

Any suggestions on how to correct this with `6.5.0-14`?

Thank you

Comment: Supported kernel stacks for a LTS are the GA (which is 5.15 for *jammy* or 22.04), and HWE (which recently moved from 6.2 or the 23.04 kernel to 6.5 from 23.10). One option is to use the GA kernel (default stack for Kubuntu 22.04 & 22.04.1 media & all Server media; .2 & later for all Desktop ISOs default to HWE which can be better for newer hardware esp. graphics)  As Ubuntu 23.04 is nearing its EOL; 6.2 is near EOL for Ubuntu.  https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack

Comment: Try again, kernel modules for 6.5 require the gcc-12, and that was just added to the hwe upgrades very recently. @guiverc Recent checks of the Ubuntu 22.04.1 Desktop ISO showed the hwe packages (much to my surprise, I too thought the .1 stayed at 5.15)! The initial kernel is 5.15, but the first update/upgrade, the 6.5 kernel is downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't happy with being stuck on an older kernel version, so I ended up replacing the Marvell board with a LSI 9207-8i controller.  I upgraded back to the latest kernel (now 6.5.0-17), and no more issues.  The drives connected to the LSI board are all performing well.  The Marvell board was inexpensive when I bought it a few years ago, but a case of yet get what you pay for.  Problem solved.